# Running container created by JIB image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jib

I am using maven jib plugin to dockerize my Spring boot based application.

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>src/main/resources/static</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp/static</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.13</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <from>
                                <image>${base.image}</image>
                            </from>
                            <to>
                                <image>${registry}/${repository}/${image}:${version}</image>
                            </to>
                            <extraDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp</extraDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

I use the following command to run in Kubernetes. Snippet from Kubernetes deployment yaml file.

```
- args:
    - -c
    - java -cp /app/libs/*:/app/resources/:/app/classes/ -Xmx2g -Xms2g com.test.Application
      --spring.config.location=/config/application.properties
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    image: ....
```

It runs fine. I am confused on running the samething using docker.

I tried the below command, But, it is not picking the applicaiton.properties file. I have my application.properties under /local/path/config folder.

> docker run IMAGE /bin/bash -c "java -cp /app/libs/*:/app/resources/:/app/classes/ -Xmx2g -Xms2g
>   com.test.Application
>   --spring.config.location=/config/application.properties" -v /local/path/config:/config/

Comment: You haven't included enough of the snippet from your Deployment to know what the `volumes:` and `volumeMounts:` looks like; also, in your `docker` command you can't put the `-v` after the `bash` command because docker run has no idea you meant the `-v` for `run`; I'm actually a little surprised that `bash` didn't whine about that, too

Comment: I tried -v right after the run command and after the image. Looks like volume is mounted but it is not honoring the argument --spring.config.location=/config/application.properties.

Comment: `java ... com.test.Application --debug` might come in handy in that case, since it will ask Spring to be more chatty. You can also _usually_ provide those settings as either environment variables or as system properties: `docker run -e SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=/... the-image bash -c "java -Dspring.config.location=/... -cp` type stuff; anyway, it sure does look like your question isn't about docker or kubernetes but rather Spring configuration principles

Comment: Separately, have you done the most obvious debugging step and actually listed what is in `/config`, via `docker run -v /local/path/config:/config the-image bash -c "/bin/ls -l /config; java -cp ..."`?